# Multi gpu rendering on cycle - low speed

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

We render nft collection on cycle (video, 180 frames, cozy studio plugin)

On RTX 3060 - 1 frame takes 8s.
On 6*3080 - 1 frame takes 5.5s.

Cuda, all videocards enabled, samples around 250, and in TASK MANAGER there is 1-14% usage of each cideocard.

Same thins on 4*3090 pc.

Tell pls what we do weong or what’s probleb?

Comment: @TheLabCat can you explain why this happenes

Comment: @Nikita no, I can’t. I think it’s been asked before, though.

Comment: @thelabcat [this Twitter thread] (https://twitter.com/andrewpprice/status/1510111512324898819?s=21&t=2eEMr7pi6I4fuE-_94Zrfg) says otherwise. maybe  I should have said “is broken “ instead

Comment: I’m sorry Nikita I don’t know anything beyond the Twitter thread